# No Printed out Twice?

Tags: java, io, iterator, hashmap, println

I have the following program which is probably way more complicated than it need to be but is mirroring a Prolog program. I get the correct output which is

No
X = kian
Yes
F = [david]
C = kian
Yes
No

Except for that last No, I know that it has to do with if(pairs.getKey() == father conditonal and the looping of while(it.hasNext()) I just don't know why it's printing out No twice and how do I fix it? Is it because I call pairs.getKey() == father twice?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class family {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        family obj = new family();
        obj.family();
    }

    public static int family(){

        String[] male = new String[100];
 String[] female = new String[100];

    male[0] = "david";
    male[1] = "kian";
    female[0] = "anna";
    female[1] = "sarah";

    List<String> father = new ArrayList<String>();
    father.add("david");
    List<String> mother = new ArrayList<String>();
    mother.add("sarah");

    parent.put(mother, "kian");
    parent.put(father, "kian");


    Iterator it = parent.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if(pairs.getKey() == father && pairs.getValue() == "sarah"){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            if(pairs.getKey() == father){
                System.out.println("F = " + pairs.getKey() + "\n" + "C = " +
                pairs.getValue() + "\n" + "Yes");
                }

                System.out.println("No");
        }
        if(pairs.getKey() == mother){
            System.out.println("X = " +
            pairs.getValue() + "\n" + "Yes");
        }

        it.remove();
    }
    return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` for `String` equality instead use `equals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show where you're instantiating your `parent` map, or what else you've added to it, but it would appear that you have an additional element in it, one whose key is not "mother" or "father". If that's the case, then:

- `if(pairs.getKey() == father && pairs.getValue() == "sarah")` conditional would evaluate to false, then,
- in your else block, `if(pairs.getKey() == father)` would also evaluate to false,
- but the `System.out.println("No");` line is outside of that conditional, so "No" is going to get printed anytime the first conditional is false, regardless of how the second conditional is evaluated.

Also, as has been noted in comments, you should be using `.equals()` to compare strings (`if(pairs.getKey().equals(father))`) rather than ==

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pairs.getKey() == father){
                System.out.println("F = " + pairs.getKey() + "\n" + "C = " +
                pairs.getValue() + "\n" + "Yes");
                }

                System.out.println("No");
```

The statement outside the curly bracket is the reason you are getting the double no when the first if statement before the one above is false.